# CSS way to align form's input elements, based on the widest label

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have a form:

```
<form action="#">
  <p>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="John Smith" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="name">What do you think about him?:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your opinion" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="name">Another Text Input:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="John Smith" />
  </p> 
</form>
```

With the following CSS:

```
form {
  width: 400px;
}

p {
  display: flex;
}

label {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

input {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

It looks the following way:

[image]

I need to align the right side of inputs, based on the widest label. That's what I want:

[image]

I don't know label's width beforehand, so bootstrap-like solutions with columns are not good here. Is there pure HTML/CSS way to achieve it, without using JS?

**PS!!**: **And I don't want to use `table`**

Comment: *PS!!: And I don't want to use table* --> you are describing a table layout so you need to use table but not necessary the `table` element, you can consider display:table

Comment: it seems you are right.

Comment: @TemaniAfif it seems I hurried with accepting table solution. What's why I don't want table solution: https://jsfiddle.net/DonTomato/4joq7adz/. There is a big empty space between labels and inputs. I need that all this space is filled with inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `p` and use CSS grid:

```css
form {
  width: 400px;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:auto 1fr;
  grid-gap:5px;
  margin:10px;
}

input {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="John Smith" />

    <label for="name">What do you think about him?:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your opinion" />

    <label for="name">Another Text Input:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="John Smith" />

</form> 


<form action="#" style="width:600px;">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="John Smith" />

    <label for="name">What do you think about him?:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your opinion" />

    <label for="name">Another Text Input:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="John Smith" />

</form>
```

Or use `display:contents` with the `p`

```css
form {
  width: 400px;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:auto 1fr;
  grid-gap:5px;
  margin:10px;
}

input {
  width:100%;
}

p {
 display:contents;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
<p>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="John Smith" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="name">What do you think about him?:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your opinion" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="name">Another Text Input:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="John Smith" />
</p>
</form> 


<form action="#" style="width:600px;">
<p>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="John Smith" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="name">What do you think about him?:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your opinion" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="name">Another Text Input:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="John Smith" />
</p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply organise it into a table. This will give you the formatting that you want.

**Edit:** Since you have specified that you don't want to use a table (and it would be better to avoid having to reorganise your html), how about styling your elements as if they were a table? I've changed my answer to keep your original html intact.

```css
form {
  display:table;
}

p {
  display:table-row;
}

label, input {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <p>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="John Smith" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="name">What do you think about him?:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your opinion" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="name">Another Text Input:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="John Smith" />
  </p> 
</form>
```

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Please could you expand as to why using a table here is inappropriate? It's a simple solution that gives the desired result.

Comment: The problem with table is that it sets width for columns automatically and proportionally to the content. You can look at the example where we can observe it https://jsfiddle.net/DonTomato/4joq7adz/1/  There is a big empty space between labels and inputs. I need that all this space is filled with inputs.

Comment: @DonTomato You can set the input width to the width of the form to make it take up maximum space. Then add white-space:nowrap on the label so that it remains on one line. https://jsfiddle.net/dp4fwojc/

Comment: better, but still... . I used 600px just for example. In real life it most likely will be 100% to fill some block in complex form. It doesn't work with % (

Answer (score 1):

You should put the flex-grow on the label :) :

```css
form {
  width: 400px;
}

p {
  display: flex;
}

label {
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <p>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="John Smith" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="name">What do you think about him?:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your opinion" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="name">Another Text Input:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="John Smith" />
  </p> 
</form>
```

Comment: Your solution has a small problem. in case we increase form's width. https://jsfiddle.net/DonTomato/c2ndsL6m/2/

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do so is, creating a table with two columns.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>label</td>
<td>input</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>label</td>
<td>input</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: not the best way. there are alot of bestest way instead of a table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example:

```css
form {
  width: 400px;
}

.form-group {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.form-group label {
  margin-right: 10px;
  flex: 1;
}

.form-group input {
  min-width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="John Smith" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">What do you think about him?:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your opinion" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Another Text Input:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="John Smith" />
  </div> 
</form>
```